# Is there a way to create a popover when a user taps on a word in a UITextview

Tags: swift4

I am trying to create a popover when a user taps on a word in a UITextview.

I am new to Swift and iOS and can't figure out how to achieve this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Troy, are you having trouble creating a pop-up style view, or how to get the word that has been selected in the UITextView?

Comment: Hi Gismay, I am having trouble making a word selectable in the textview so it can act like a button to open a popover view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your view controller (i.e. the one containing your UITextView) is also a UITextViewDelegate. Also make sure that your UITextView has it's isSelectable set to true.

Then add the textViewDidChangeSelection function, for example

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView)
{
    let selectedText:UITextRange = textView.selectedTextRange!
    print("You selected ", textView.text(in: selectedText)!)
}
```

This will give you the string that has been selected. You can then pass that to your popover code.